# Swift 4 Track Battery Level

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background, observers

I am trying to track the battery level of my phone in an own app. The aim is, that it is going to store time and the percentage every x minutes and always in the moment it's changing the level.
I know how to get the batteryLevel (and maybe the state, which is similar) with code like this:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

var batteryLevel: Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}
```

That is working very good in my code.
Also there is the possibility of monitoring moments of changement:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil, using: batteryLevelChanged)
func batteryLevelChanged(notification: Notification) -> Void {
    print(batteryLevel) // I am just printing, the stuff with the txt file doesn't matter
}
```

The timer works like this:

```
var timer: Timer! = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And then there is a function named timerFunction which also gives the current percentage like the other one above.
func updateTimer() {
    print(batteryLevel)
}
In fact, print is just a placeholder for saving a new entry into a text file, which would have been a very long function out of context of the question.

Everything works quite well but I am falling about a very stupid mistake where I don't know how to solve it:
Unfortunately (well, fortunately for the rest of the phone and system) the system stops running the app in the background after a while (mostly 3-6 minutes). This is good for the system, but very bad for the app.
Do you know a good idea how to run these two tasks in the background (monitoring if percentage changes and run it every 2 min)?

Comment: kindly show your timer function

Comment: when the app is backgrounded the app only has a few minutes at most to do stuff before it is stopped from actively running code. So you cannot do it like that. ironically, this is probably to help resource usage such as battery, cpu, network etc

Comment: @MaheshDangar Added this. But in fact, it's just a stub, I don't want to disturb my question with a very large code of saving a next information into a text file.

Comment: @Scriptable You are totally right. But I am sure there is a way to do, there are so many apps like mail apps checking for mails every 5 minutes or so

Comment: Most apps use push notification to be notified about new messages etc.  The built-in mail app, like all Apple apps, can do things that your apps can't.  There is no way to continually perform arbitrary tasks in the background on iOS.  You can read about supported background modes in the iOS application programming guide

Comment: @FranzFerdinand PaulW is right, Apple apps have access to private API's that we  don't and can do things that we can't. Check this guide which shows what things you can do in the background and what background modes are available: https://www.raywenderlich.com/890-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started